# Highcharts multiple series data from SQL Database

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi I am creating a dashboard that reads the data from SQL and display a chart in ASP.net.

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

    }]
```

for example that's my data coming from SQL and i created an array to get each data per row myarray=[name,data1,data2,data3,.....,data12]

this is how I get the data

```
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "myService.asmx/CBPmethod",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (Result) {
                Result = Result.d;
                var data = [];
                var mydata = new Array();
                for (var i=0 in Result) {
                    var serie = new Array(Result[i].Metric, Result[i].Nov15, Result[i].Dec15, Result[i].Jan16, Result[i].Q1, Result[i].Feb16, Result[i].Mar16, Result[i].Apr16, Result[i].Q2, Result[i].May16, Result[i].Jun16, Result[i].Jul16, Result[i].Q3, Result[i].Aug16, Result[i].Sep16, Result[i].Oct16, Result[i].Q4);
                    data.push(serie);
                }
               DrawChart(data);
            },
            error: function (Result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });


    function DrawChart(series1) {

        $('#container110').highcharts({

            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Test'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            credit: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: series1
            }]
        });
    }
</script>
```

how can i create a loop for series in highcharts to display a column chart dynamically?

thanks!

Comment: If you are binding the data from the front end you just need to use [For each](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) loop for this.

Comment: I created a web service to access the data from SQL server.

Comment: Do you want to re-display the chart repeatedly?

Comment: No, I want to display a chart from a dynamic data coming from the SQL Server.

Comment: Please post exemplary data received from ajax call in `Result` in success function.